# why my log doesn't show newlines in notepad only in writer (Java)

Tags: java

I'm developing an app in Java which captures string and generates a log text

```
public static void createTXTLog(String pathLog, String textLog){
    try{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathLog));
        writer.write(textLog);
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("An error occured while generating log txt: \n" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

when I open my log generated by this method it shows in notepad something like this:

```
09-12-2013 17:48:18 :[INF] Creando la conexion a la BD... 09-12-2013 17:48:18 :[eW003][ERR][inicioProceso] Error en la creacion de la conexion a la BD: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor The Connection descriptor used by the client was:180.176.40.134:1522:DBDESAS
```

But if I open this on Writer it shows properly:

```
09-12-2013 17:48:18 :[INF] Creando la conexion a la BD... 

09-12-2013 17:48:18 :[eW003][ERR][inicioProceso] Error en la creacion de la conexion a la BD: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
180.176.40.134:1522:DBDESAS
```

Any idea how to fix it in notepad???
thanks in advance

Comment: different OSs have different line seperators:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()

Comment: Where are you writing the actual newline ? Note that the BufferedWriter has a `.newLine()` method you could use if you don't want to manually write the newlines. Using a PrintWriter instead of BufferedWriter/FileWriter would give you convenient methods to write newlines too.

Comment: Notepad.exe is just the most stupid program on earth, right after cmd.exe. Use a better tool to watch your files, like utraedit or even jedit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only returning a new-line, not a carriage-return and new-line; which is what you need for a Windows text file.  You could change this to the following.

```
System.out.println("An error occured while generating log txt:" + System.lineSeparator() + e);
```

Or if you're running on something other than Windows but will be looking at your file in Notepad in Windows, you could do this.

```
System.out.println("An error occured while generating log txt: \r\n" + e);
```

I took the liberty of removing the redundant `toString()` call.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly because you use `"\n"` instead of `"\r\n"` which the line separator in Windows.